# How to Import AAR file in the flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, aar, flutter-plugin

I am working in a flutter plugin and want to import an `.aar` project in android part of the plugin. I have tried opening the android project and importing the `.aar` project by importing the module, including it in `setting.gradle` and adding it in dependency of `build.grade` (like any other native android project). However, when I run the flutter project, the `.aar` project is not found.

The error I get is

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_plugin_andriod'
>
> Project with path ':commonlib' could not be found in project ':flutter_plugin_andriod'.

[image]

Anybody with the fix ?

Answer (score 2):

Put your .aar in Android/app/libs
In Android/app/build.gradle you import the aar :

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation files('libs/myaarlibr.aar')
}
```

After this your .aar is ready for use

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

Create folder `libs` in plugin_folder/android/ and put your *.aar file there.

In plugin_folder/android/build.gradle

```
rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':plugin_name').file('libs')
        }
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation (name: 'file-sdk-name', ext: 'aar')
    ...
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work either for me. Got the following error
`* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':my_plugin_name'.
> Project with path ':plugin_name' could not be found in root project 'android'.`

Comment: try replacing "implementation" with "api", it worked for me .

Comment: You can solve this  `Project with path <plugin_name> could not be found in root project <project_name>` error by adding `include ':<plugin_name>'` to settings.gradle in your android folder. @Kosmonaft

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.

- create a lib folder in directory where the build.gradle is and place your aar file in the folder.
- Then add  **flatDir {   dirs project(':plugin_name').file('libs')}** in your **rootProject.allprojects**
- Then add dependency in the build. file in the dependencies section as: 
  **api(name: 'your_aar_file_name', ext: 'aar')**  
  **Note:** Make sure to add all the dependencies included in gradle.build file (if your aar file depends on any gradle.build file of its own)  in the dependencies section of your application build.gradle file . This was the main issue in my case.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Got the following errror
"* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':myPlugin'.
> Could not find method api() for arguments [{name=my_arr_file, ext=aar}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
"

Comment: Where is rootProject.allprojects ?

Comment: @CamiloOrtegón its a  block in you build.gradle file if its not in your file just create one

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue at Flutter's Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28195) which at this day is still open.

The only way I could solve and import an AAR library into a Flutter Plugin was following these steps:

1. Rename `.aar` file to `.zip`
2. Extract zip files and copy `classes.jar` into `libs` folder of you Flutter plugin
3. Rename it to the same `.aar` file, so you won't get lost when importing it
4. Add the `.jar` to your `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

5. Build the plugin normally.

Answer (score 0):

This took me some time to figure out.

Create an empty folder in your Flutter android and add your aar file in my case the folder was called ftsdk and excute this command (you might need to brew install maven)

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=facetec-sdk-9.6.51-minimal.aar \
-DgroupId=com.facetec.sdk \
-DartifactId=default \
-Dversion=1.0.0 \
-Dpackaging=aar \
-DlocalRepositoryPath=./repository
```

This will generate a local maven repository in the same folder (if you leave out '-DlocalRepositoryPath' then it will default to your main maven folder usually '/Users/myUser/.m2'

In my Flutter Android build. gradle I included this directory under repositories (make sure its the allprojects repositories)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    //mavenLocal() use this line if you let it generate in the default maven folder in /Users/myUser/.m2
    maven {
        url "$projectDir/ftsdk/repository"
    }
}
```

}

Then in your build gradle dependencies you can add it as follows

```
android{
...
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.facetec.sdk:default:1.0.0';
    }
...
}
```

Answer inspired by this king: https://alessiobianchi.eu/blog/obfuscated-aar-local-maven/