# How to use and call aar file in a flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, aar

I had integrated an aar file into my flutter project and i dont know how to call the classes in it

please help me guys !

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73724659/14577209)

Comment: @Maleesha97 i already saw it, it make just implememtation, for me i want to know the way i can call classes

Comment: For that you need to implement platform (Native Android) code and call the methods using an [EventChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html). You can communicate between flutter code and native code using this.